# WWW::Mechanize : How to upload file under different file name?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

How to make WWW::Mechanize upload file under different file name?

I would like web server to see/record file name different from file name on my computer.

Comment: I don't know if there is an easy way to do this except by creating your own custom request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $file = [
    'filename-on-disk.txt', # The file you'd like to upload.
    'filename-for-upload.txt', # The filename you'd like to give the web server.
    'Content-type' => 'text/plain' # Any other flags you'd like to add go here.
];

$mech->post("http://example.com/upload.cgi", [
    'upload' => $file
]);
```

Taken from:
https://gist.github.com/gaurav/253111#file-file-upload-pl

Comment: ... and documented in `perldoc HTTP::Request::Common`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hard link:

```
link "file_name_on_your_computer","desired_new_name";
# Code to upload the newly created link
unlink "desired_new_name";
```

**Notes**

- You need not worry about disk space usage if you're using a large file: the file is not duplicated, the hard link is simply a new name for the same inode.
- This solution is limited to just those filesystems that support hard links. If you're on Windows, this may end up creating and uploading only a shortcut to your original file.

Comment: I would prefer a solution without even temporary changes in the file system. I hope a cleaner alternative to your suggestion will emerge :-)